# Check if combobox contains value of list vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have list with duplicates values

```
 Dim lstPlayerValidate As New List(Of Integer)
 Dim duplicates = lstPlayerValidate.Where(Function(x) lstPlayerValidate.Where(Function(y) x = y).Count() > 1).Distinct().ToList
```

Now I want check if comboxes contains any value from this list. 
I do it so:

```
If cmbPlayer.Items.Contains(duplicates) Then 'do something
```

My combobox has Item as `List(Of Player)`, where PlayerID is value which I want compare. Perhaps I'm doing an unnecessary job creating another list with only id values. But I don't now how I can do it

Comment: Does the CBO use a datasource or is the data directly in the items collection?

Comment: a datasource. data comes from db

Comment: You can test whether one collection contains any items from another collection like this: `If collection1.Any(Function(item) collection2.Contains(item)) Then`.  You can test whether one collection contains any items that match some aspect of any items from another collection like this: `If collection1.Any(Function(item1) collection2.Any(Function(item2) item1.SomeProperty = item2.SomeProperty)) Then`.

Comment: You can also use the `Intersect` method, e.g. `If collection1.Intersect(collection2).Any() Then`.